# asp.net mvc, generate url by custom route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

i have created application, where url generates depends on database values.
i parse these urls without any problem and get controller and action from database in my route handler.

but when i try to generate url, i get troubles.

in my case, it seems like:

view

```
@Html.ActionLink("more", MVC.Blog.Post(item.Alias)) // i use T4MVC
```

MyRouteConstraint

```
public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
{
    if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.UrlGeneration)
    {
        var data = GetDataFromDbByControllerActionAndParameters(values);
        if (data == null)
            return false;
        var valuesToRemove = new List<string>();
        var path = GenerateUrlByData(data, valuesToRemove);
        values.Remove("controller");
        values.Remove("action");
        valuesToRemove.ForEach(v => values.Remove(v)); // remove values that is already used in path
        values.Add("all", path) // path = "blog/post/postalias"
        return true;
    }
    //  skipped code
}
```

route rule

```
routes.MapRoute("Locations", "{*all}", 
    constraints: new { all = new LocationConstraints() },
    defaults: new { }, 
    namespaces: new []{typeof(BaseController).Namespace}).RouteHandler = new LocationRouteHandler();
```

and as result i got url like this

```
localhost:8553/?Controller=Blog&Action=Post&alias=postalias
```

but expect like this

```
localhost:8553/blog/post/postalias
```

how can I generate url? where it should be? i think not in the constrant, but why it is invoked in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In my MVC application the closest route that matches the one you have is the one below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyRouteName",
    url: "{SomeFolder}/{SomePageName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { routeConstraint = new MyRouteConstraint() }
);
```

`SomeFolder` can be fixed or changed from the database while `SomePageName` will be changed to a different value from database. The `url` should be whatever URL you want to match with this route and the one that will be replaced by the value from the database. The `defaults` address the Controller and Action that will render the page in the end of the MVC cycle. The `constraints` will lead to your Match method described.

With this configuration I have URLs like `www.project.com/SomeFolder/SomePageNameFromDatabase`.